# How to convert multiple SQL LEFT JOIN statement with where clause to LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, left-join

Is there any way to convert following SQL statement into LINQ?

```
select ve.EntityID
         , fin1.FinanceStat as FinanceStat_New
         , fin2.FinanceStat as FinanceStat_Old
    from ValuationEvents_PIT_New as ve
    left join FinStat_New as Fin1
    on ve.EntityID = Fin1.EntityID
    left join FinStat_Old as Fin2
    on ve.EntityID = Fin2.EntityID
    where Fin1.FinanceStat ne Fin2.FinanceStat
        and Fin2.FinanceStat is not null
        and charindex(Fin1.FinanceStat, 'abc') < 1
        and charindex(Fin1.FinanceStat, 'xyz') < 1
```

Here is my version of it, but I need extra pair of eyes to look at it.

```
var result = (from ve in valuationEventsPit
       join fsn in finStatNew on ve.EntityId equals fsn.EntityID into veFsn
       from fin1 in veFsn.DefaultIfEmpty()
       join fso in finStatOld on ve.EntityId equals fso.EntityID into veFso
       from fin2 in veFso.DefaultIfEmpty()
       select new
       {
            ve.EntityId,
            FinStatNew1 = fin1 == null ? null : fin1.FinanceStat,
            FinStatNew2 = fin2 == null ? null : fin2.FinanceStat
       }).
       Where(x => x.FinStatNew1 != null &&
            x.FinStatNew2 != null &&
            x.FinStatNew1 != x.FinStatNew2 &&
            !(x.FinStatNew1.Contains("abc")) &&
            !(x.FinStatNew1.Contains("xyz"))).ToList();
```

The reason I am excluding x.FinStatNew1 == null because of the charindex(Fin1.FinanceStat, 'abc') < 1, which will always return 0 if x.FinStatNew1 is not null and 'abc' or 'xyz' is not there and if x.FinStatNew1 is null then it will return null and condition still will be false (null < 0).

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could reduce that query even more and rearrange some things to make it more readable.  Based on the original query and these are actually LINQ to objects queries, I'd try this:

```
const string con1 = "abc";
const string con2 = "xyz";
var query =
    from ve in valuationEventPit
    join fsn in finStatNew on ve.EntityId equals fsn.EntityID
    join fso in finStatOld on ve.EntityId equals fso.EntityID
    let FinStatNew = fsn.FinanceStat
    let FinStatOld = fso.FinanceStat
    where FinStatNew != FinStatOld && FinStatOld != null
       && new[]{con1,con2}.All(con => !FinStatNew.Contains(con))
    select new { ve.EntityId, FinStatNew, FinStatOld };
```

The left join is not necessary here.  Since you exclude the null values, we could just ignore them then and do the inner join.

Comment: Thanks for helping.  This is not LINQ to SQL or EF, this is LINQ to Objects, and I have to do check for null, otherwise I will have NullReferenceException.

Comment: Ah, in that case, there are a bunch more things we could do here then.  I'll update.

Comment: Thanks again.  I see you are using now Inner Join, because I've done it this way.  I am not sure if my translation is correct, otherwise I would not ask for advise :).  Do you still believe that query that I have is performing inner join, even though it is using left join?  Please read original SQL instead of my code.

Comment: Well the original performs the left (outer) join.  And if `FinanceStat` was not nullable, I don't think we'd be able to do the inner.  However since you said you were doing a LINQ to objects query, it _could_ be `null` and you explicitly throw out the null values in the original and yours.  So there would be no point in including values that could be null in the first place, hence my suggestion to use the inner join.